# MySQL - Slow query using group-by

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if there is a reason for the slowness of this query, or if it's just the size of the table. It has about 27 million records. I want the max "as of date" for each class.

```
SELECT MAX(`as_of_date`)
                FROM `mstar_valuation_ratios`
                GROUP BY class_id
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `valuations` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `class_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `as_of_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `valuation` DECIMAL(19,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `class_id` (`class_id`, `as_of_date`),
    INDEX `as_of_date` (`as_of_date`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Results:

> /* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 30,589  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1
>   query: 3.922 sec. (+ 45.843 sec. network) */

Comment: Create an index on class_id by itself.

Comment: How do you know which date belongs to which class?